# How much does a CLW potion heal?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, potions

Normally I would state this is CL 1 and thus 1d8+1. On the other hand,  brew potion has the requirement "caster level 3".  Does this mean that CLW potions should be 1d8+3?

Comment: [Related] [How much does a “Potion of cure light wounds” heal?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45657/how-much-does-a-potion-of-cure-light-wounds-heal)  This might even be a duplicate, except for the fact they are different systems.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most potions are created using the minimum caster level required to cast the associated spell. So for Cure Light Wounds that woudl mean CL1, and it would heal 1d8+1. While increasing the caster level is possible this would also increase the cost as well.

From the [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/creatingMagicItems.htm):

> A creator can create an item at a lower caster level than her own, but never lower than the minimum level needed to cast the needed spell.

From the same page on the table to determine the cost of a potion:

> Costs assume that the creator makes the potion at the minimum caster level.

Comment: Also, the cost listed for the 'default' CLW potion makes sense if it's 50(gp) x 1 (spell level) x 1 (caster level). If it was brewed with caster level 3, it should've cost 150gp instead of 50gp.